# Having problems implementing box-shadow on table rows

Tags: css, html-table, box-shadow

I am trying to add a focus state to table rows in my table via border and box shadow but I'm not able to get the box shadow working properly.  The box shadow renders on all sides except the right for some reason.

I have an example of the work here and the relevant CSS is below - to add focus state click on the dropdown arrow - https://codepen.io/schins02/pen/bXmQQo

```
.table tbody .expanded.tr-focused {
  box-shadow: 0 -0.3px 0 0.3px #09865e, 0px -2px .2px 0 #cff1e6;
  transition: 300ms box-shadow ease;
}

.table tbody .expanded.tr-focused + tr {
  box-shadow: 0 0.3px 0 0.3px #09865e, 0 3px 1px 0 #cff1e6;
  transition: 300ms box-shadow ease;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The box-shadow appears on the right correctly in my Chrome 76 and Firefox 68 on Windows 10. I can send you screenshots if it helps.

Comment: What's the problem with your code ?? It's seems working fine for me

Comment: I believe only the border is rendering on the right, not the box shadow on Chrome 75.  On Firefox 68 it looks like the same is happening on the issue is on the left side.  I'm not super front endy so hopefully I'm not missing something obvious.  I saw an example where someone added the box-shadow to the tds, that might be a good workaround.